# Cannot get the full value of a URL passed in the query string

Tags: php, html, url

I want to send a URL to another page like this:

`http://localhost/l.php?u=http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo&id=13`

Where the URL `http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo&id=13` is the value of the parameter `u`.

In the `l.php` file my result looks like this:

```
echo $_GET['u']; // http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo
                 // &id=13 is missing
```

What is wrong with this? I want to redirect to the URL `http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo&id=13`, but the `&id=13` part is missing.

I create links with `preg_replace`. I cannot apply a PHP function to the `$1` variable

```
preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" 
href=\"l.php?u=$1\">$1</a>",$text);
```

Comment: Why are you using preg_replace? Give me the reason please.

Comment: To find all links that contain in text where text is retrieve from the database. And it can have many links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
preg_replace_callback("/(https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", function($m){
    return "<a target='_blank' href='l.php?u=".urlencode($m[0])."'>".$m[0]."</a>";
}, $text);
```

This will replace all links with anchor tags & will encode the URL as well.

Comment: Try this & post your feedback.

Comment: Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @ApulGupta I don't want to be rude, but this doesn't answer the question in general. The real question is: **Why can't I use an ampersand in an URL?**. You have to add this information in your answer to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an ampersand in your URL. When you use that, you define a new URL parameter. Use urlencode before sending it and urldecode when you need the URL.

E.g.: `urlencode('http://localhost/l.php?u=http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo&id=13');`

output: `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fl.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.simplesite.com%3Fview%3Dphoto%26id%3D13`

To decode it again:

`urldecode('http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fl.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.simplesite.com%3Fview%3Dphoto%26id%3D13');`

output: `http://localhost/l.php?u=http://www.simplesite.com?view=photo&id=13`

Comment: You should edit your answer as this is not what user is asking for.

Comment: @ApulGupta Infact, this is what the user wants. His URL is broken because of the ampersand. That's why he has to use `urlencode` and `urldecode`

Comment: I do not agree with the downvote, perfectly clear and good answer, which gives a solution to the problem the OP is facing